# Validar campo vacíos previo a ingresar en una tabla ASP CORE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dándole funcionalidad a mi formulario sigo con la validación de evitar añadir una columna si no tiene datos, con lo cual aplico el siguiente código validando si es null pero al parecer se me esta escapando algo que causa que se ingrese y en la columna me muestra `undefined`.

```
function AnadirFilaPresup() {
let hasError = false;
var a = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val();
var b = $("#Nom_Pac").val();
var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();
var valor1 = c;
if (valor1 == null || valor1.length == 0) {
    alert('Error, Realiza una Selección');
    hasError = true;
}
else { var cadena = valor1.substring(5, 20); }

var d = $("#Rut_Pac").val();
var e = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val();
var f = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val();
var g = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val();
var h = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val();
var i = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val();
var j = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val();
var k = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val();
console.log(valor1);
if (valor1 != null) {
    $("#tblTratamiento tbody").append("<tr><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + cadena + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e +
        "</td><td>" + f + "</td><td>" + g + "</td><td>" + h + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + j + "</td><td>" + k + "</td></tr>");
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val('');
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val('');
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val('');
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val('0');
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val('0');
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val('0');
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val('0');
}
if (hasError) event.preventDefault();
```

}

Aquí adjunto el código en el cual mando a llamar al método en mi botón

```
 <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-center">
                                                    <label>Nombre de Paciente para Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input id="Nom_Pac" value="@pac_nombre" type="text" readonly placeholder="NOMBRE PACIENTE" class="form-control text-center" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-center">
                                                    <label>RUT de Paciente para Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input id="Rut_Pac" value="@pac_rut" type="text" readonly placeholder="RUT PACIENTE" class="form-control text-center" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>COD. Presupuesto:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD" type="text" readonly placeholder="CODIGO PRESUPUESTO" class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Profesional:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Odontologo_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Profesional:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Odontologo_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
             "ESCOGA UN PROFESIONAL", new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Dentadura:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Dentadura:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
"ESCOGA UN TIPO DE DENTADURA", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SeleccionDentadura()" });
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Pieza Dental:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Pieza_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Pieza Dental:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN", new SelectList("", "Text", "Text"),
                    "ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Tratamiento_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Tratamiento_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
             "ESCOGA UN TRATAMIENTO", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SeleccionTratamiento()" })
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Valor Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Porcentaje Dscto. Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR" type="number" onchange="Dscto_Trat_Presup()" class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Descuento Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_DES" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_DES" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Total Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Estado Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_EST_ELI" type="text" readonly placeholder="ESTADO TRATAMIENTO" class="form-control" />
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Estado Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_EST_ELI" type="text" readonly value="V" class="form-control" />
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_EST_ELI" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light" onclick="AnadirFilaPresup(event)">+</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light">-</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Esto es un copia/pega sin sentido:  `if (hasError) event.preventDefault();` porque `event` no esta definido antes:  `TypeError: event is undefined`.  Revisa bien de donde lo has copiado y que representa `event` en ese caso para intentar comprender tu error.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar guiándome en que estoy cometiendo de manera errónea por favor?

Comment: Agrega en tu pregunta el codigo HTML que llama a AnadirFilaPresup() o lo que sea que llame a esa función, para poder indicarte mejor como cazar el evento que la llama.

Comment: Ok, ya hice la modificacion

Comment: Podrías hacer la vista tipada y validarlo con Fluent Validation, Data Annotations. Solo veo código en JS y nada de C# relacionado, ¿falta editar la pregunta?

Comment: Vaya, pensaba que era un boton tipo submit... Entonces lo del event.preventDefault no parece tener sentido ni relacion con tu problema.

Comment: Básicamente la respuesta a tu pregunta @fredyfx el boton de añadir es para realizar el ingreso del contenido de los input a la tabla y una vez que necesite o termine de realizar el presupuesto doy click en guardar en donde haria uso de submit.

Comment: ¿Y puedes agregar a la pregunta el HTML donde estan todos esos id?

Comment: claro lo acabo de hacer , funciona perfectamente porque me permite hacer el ingreso de datos a la tabla el problema es cuando quiero validar si el primer campo no tiene datos para que no deje ingresar esa fila sino esta lleno el input

Comment: O sea, si te he entendido bien, ¿quieres que deje de procesarse la función si aparece el alert('Error, Realiza una Selección');?  Lo digo porque segun veo, lo que quieres es bajar el `}` que aparece al final de `else { var cadena = valor1.substring(5, 20); }` hasta casi el final de la función, ¿no?

Comment: Si efectivamente si la persona se olvida de hacer una seleccion o lo deja en blanco lanza el alert y al tratar de insertar la fila no le permite porque no tiene lleno el input y asi sucesivamente con cada input, solo puse de ejemplo el primero para posteriormente continuar

Comment: Y en cuanto al `undefined`, leyendo jquery veo que dice esto: `The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty collection, it returns undefined.` Por lo que deduzco que, a haber un condicional `if` en tu codigo el valor no es `null` como tu pretendes porque quizas no ha sacado ese campo #MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON aun, por lo tanto no existe y devuelve `undefined` en lugar de null.

Comment: A riesgo de parecer pesado (que lo soy) ¿no sera que el id que llamas en jquery aqui: `var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();`  no se corresponde con lo que intentas crear aquí?  `@Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON"` (fijate en el punto que separa `PRESUPUESTO` de `PRE_` en lugar de `_`.  Quizas por eso no devuelve el `null` sino un `undefined`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133050/discussion-between-carrobe90-and-masterguru).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con la ayuda y colaboración de compañeros programadores, pongo la solución, al parecer estaba organizando mal los if.

```
function AnadirFilaPresup(event) {
let hasError = false;
var a = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val();
var b = $("#Nom_Pac").val();
var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();
var d = $("#Rut_Pac").val();
var e = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val();
var f = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val();
var g = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val();
var h = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val();
var i = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val();
var j = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val();
var k = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val();
if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val().length == 0) {
    console.log("ERROR: MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD");
    hasError = true;
}
else if ($("#Nom_Pac").val() == null || $("#Nom_Pac").val().length == 0) {
    console.log("ERROR: Nom_Pac");
    hasError = true;
}
else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val().length == 0) {
    alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección del Profesional');
    console.log("ERROR: PRE_COD_ODON");
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").focus();
    hasError = true;
}
else if ($("#Rut_Pac").val() == null || $("#Rut_Pac").val().length == 0) {
    console.log("ERROR: Rut_Pac");
    hasError = true;
}
else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val().length == 0) {
    alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección de la Dentadura');
    console.log("ERROR: PRE_DEN_PAC");
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").focus();
    hasError = true;
}
else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val().length == 0) {
    alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección de la Pieza Dental');
    console.log("ERROR: PRE_PIE_DEN");
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").focus();
    hasError = true;
}
else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val().length == 0) {
    alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección del Tratamiento');
    console.log("ERROR: PRE_TRA_PAC");
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").focus();
    hasError = true;
}
else {
    hasError = false;
    if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val() != null && $("#Nom_Pac").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val() != null
        && $("#Rut_Pac").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val() != null
        && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val() != null) {
        var cadena = c.substring(5, 20);
        $("#tblTratamiento tbody").append("<tr><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + cadena + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e +
            "</td><td>" + f + "</td><td>" + g + "</td><td>" + h + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + j + "</td><td>" + k + "</td></tr>");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val('');
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val('');
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val('');
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val('0');
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val('0');
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val('0');
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val('0');
        hasError = false;
    }
    else {
        hasError = true;
        console.log("ERROR:! NO SE INGRESA NINGUNA FILA");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

De antemano agradecido con todos.!

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas logrado :-)